# Python Pandas: Skip if there is no data then continue writing into excel

Tags: python, pandas

How do I skip an error when I am not looping? I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = 'structure_name_Q4_SV.xlsx'
active_file = 'active_cases.csv'


df = pd.read_excel(file)
df1 = pd.read_csv(active_file)



active_cases_sv = df1.query('program_name == "sample"').pivot_table(values='value', 
                         index=['country','facility_name','program_name','age_category','gender'], 
                         columns=['year','quarter'],  
                          aggfunc=np.sum,
                          margins=True,
                          margins_name="Total",
                          fill_value = '-')

single_session = df.query('encounterType == "encounter.sample.closure"' 
                                 ).query('question == "Reasons for Closure"'
                                        ).query('value_all == "Single Session"'
                                               ).pivot_table(values='patient_id', 
                                                 index=['country','FacilityName_x','age_category','gender'], 
                                                 columns=['encounter_year','encounter_quarter'],  
                                                  aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique,
                                                  margins=True,
                                                  margins_name="Total",
                                                  fill_value = '-')



single_session_sv = df.query('encounterType == "encounter.sample.closure"' 
                            ).query('question == "Reasons for Closure"'
                                   ).query('value_all == "Single Session"'
                                          ).query('SV == "Yes"'
                                                 ).pivot_table(values='patient_id', 
                                                    index=['country','FacilityName_x','age_category','gender'], 
                                                    columns=['encounter_year','encounter_quarter'],  
                                                    aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique,
                                                    margins=True,
                                                    margins_name="Total",
                                                    fill_value = '-')


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test_data.xlsx', engine = 'xlsxwriter')



active_cases_sv.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Active cases')
single_session.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Single session')
single_session_sv.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Single session SV')

writer.save()
writer.close()

print ("done")
```

The code works fine when data is found in the dataframe with the queries I have added. The problem is sometimes the dataset may not have 'single session' but have 'active_cases_sv' and 'single_session_sv'.

So it gives me an error 'no object to concatenate'

So what I would like to do is to have the code check every code set (not sure how to call it: i.e. active_cases_sv, single_session, single_session_sv) and if there is value, then add it in excel, if there's not, then skip and move to the next set of code.

Thanks in advance for the guidance.

John

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [empty](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html), then for your code, change:

```
active_cases_sv.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Active cases')
single_session.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Single session')
single_session_sv.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Single session SV')
```

to

```
if not active_cases_sv.empty:
    active_cases_sv.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Active cases')
if not single_session.empty:
    single_session.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Single session')
if not single_session_sv.empty:
    single_session_sv.to_excel(writer,sheet_name = 'Single session SV')
```

You might need to add some extra logic to make sure the Excel file is not blank.